# Extracting enumeration values from an XML Schema with Python

Tags: python, xsd, python-xmlschema

From an XML Schema using `xmlschema` package, I extracted an XsdEnumerationFacets like the one below

```py
XsdEnumerationFacets(['OP1', 'OP2', 'OP3', 'OP3', 'OP4', ...])
```

How can I extract the possible values from it? ('OP1', 'OP2', 'OP3', 'OP3', 'OP4' and so on in this case).

I had one idea to convert it into string (`str(enum)`), and parse it, but if it's long, the last elements are not included.

(I have xmlschema==1.9.2 and Python 3.9.)

Example:

`schema.xsd` is

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  targetNamespace="http://www.java2s.com" xmlns="http://www.java2s.com"
  elementFormDefault="qualified">

    <xs:element name = "Tshirt">
       <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
             <xs:element name = "Color" type = "clothesColorType" />
             <xs:element name = "Size" type = "clothesSizeType" />
          </xs:sequence>
       </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="clothesSizeType">
       <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="S" />
          <xs:enumeration value="M" />
          <xs:enumeration value="L" />
          <xs:enumeration value="XL" />
       </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="clothesColorType">
       <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
          <xs:enumeration value="Black" />
          <xs:enumeration value="White" />
          <xs:enumeration value="Green" />
          <xs:enumeration value="Blue" />
       </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

My code:

```py
import xmlschema

schema = xmlschema.XMLSchema("schema.xsd")
tshirt = schema.elements["Tshirt"]

enumerate_values = {}
for c in tshirt.type.content:
    for comp in c.type.iter_components():
        if isinstance(comp, xmlschema.validators.XsdEnumerationFacets):
            enumerate_values[c.name.split("}")[1]] = str(comp)

print(enumerate_values)
```

That creates me the dictionary:

```py
{'Color': "XsdEnumerationFacets(['Black', 'White', 'Green', 'Blue'])", 'Size': "XsdEnumerationFacets(['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL'])"}
```

Instead of `"XsdEnumerationFacets(['Black', 'White', 'Green', 'Blue'])"` as a value, I would like to have  `['Black', 'White', 'Green', 'Blue']`. And I don't want to parse this string. As I mentioned for longer value list the last elements are substituted by ellipses (`...`), so parsing the string will give me a false or partial result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    import xmlschema
    
    schema = xmlschema.XMLSchema("schema.xsd")
    tshirt = schema.elements["Tshirt"]
    
    enumerate_values = {}
    for c in tshirt.type.content:
        for comp in c.type.iter_components():
            if isinstance(comp, xmlschema.validators.XsdEnumerationFacets):
                enumerate_values[c.local_name] = [x.get("value") for x in comp]
    
    print(enumerate_values)
```

returns:
`{'Color': ['Black', 'White', 'Green', 'Blue'], 'Size': ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL']}`

Answer (score 0):

I created get_enum_values function to get the values from an XsdEnumerationFacets object. This is the whole code, that works with the xsd file in the question.

```py
import xmlschema

schema = xmlschema.XMLSchema("schema.xsd")
tshirt = schema.elements["Tshirt"]

def get_enum_values(enum):
    """Get values from XsdEnumerationFacets"""
    return [e.items()[0][1] for e in  enum._elements]

enumerate_values = {}
for c in tshirt.type.content:
    for comp in c.type.iter_components():
        if isinstance(comp, xmlschema.validators.XsdEnumerationFacets):
            enumerate_values[c.name.split("}")[1]] = get_enum_values(comp)  # Changed

print(enumerate_values)
```

That gives me that I want:

```py
{'Color': ['Black', 'White', 'Green', 'Blue'], 'Size': ['S', 'M', 'L', 'XL']}
```